# Why does variable declaration work well as the condition of for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, language-lawyer, declaration

What's the return value/type of a declaration like `int i = 5`?

Why doesn't compile this code:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(void) {
    std::cout << "Hello";
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    for(foo(); (int i = 5)==5 ; ++i)std::cout << i; 
}
```

while this does

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(void) {
    std::cout << "Hello";
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    for(foo(); int i = 5; ++i)std::cout << i; 
}
```

Comment: Because `int i = 5` is not a valid expression? And you need a valid expression in the parentheses.

Comment: Even if your second program compiles, you will be struck in an infinite loop. It will keep printing '5' to the terminal.

Comment: What makes things even more interesting is that if you initialize i to 0 it returns false.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for#Syntax) loop requires *condition* to be either an expression or a declaration:

> condition -   either
>
> - an expression which is contextually convertible to bool. This expression is evaluated before each iteration, and if it yields false,
>   the loop is exited.
> - a declaration of a single variable with a brace-or-equals initializer. the initializer is evaluated before each iteration, and
>   if the value of the declared variable converts to false, the loop is
>   exited.

The 1st code doesn't work because `(int i = 5)==5` is not a valid [expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions) at all. (It's not a declaration either.) The operand of `operator==` is supposed to be an expression too, but `int i = 5` is a declaration, not an expression.

The 2nd code works because `int i = 5` matches the 2nd valid case for *condition*; a declaration of a single variable with a equals initializer. The value of `i` will be converted to `bool` for judgement; which is always `5`, then leads to an infinite loop.

Comment: I had no idea you could declare a variable in the condition part of a for loop!

Answer (score 2):

This code acutally complies:

```
for (foo(); int i = 5 == 5; ++i)
```

It checks if `5 == 5` and set i to this boolean result (which is 1) -> infinite loop

```
for(foo(); int i = 5; ++i)
```

This simply checks the value of `i` after being set to 5, so... when converted to `bool` it's always `true` as well -> infinite loop

Comment: `i != NULL` is a little weird, you might mean `i != false`?

Comment: Since NULL == 0, i don't see anything weird here, i isn't a boolean.Anyway, the answer above is WAY better ;)

Comment: More precisely, the value of `i` will be converted to `bool`, then used for judgement; `NULL` or `0` isn't involed in this process. Anyway, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of a for loop in C programming language is as follow:

```
for ( init; condition; increment ) {
   statement(s);
}
```

> The init step is executed first, and only once. You can use init to
>   declare and initialize any loop control variables.
>
> Next, the condition is evaluated. If it is true, the body of the loop
>   is executed. If it is false, the body of the loop does not execute and
>   the flow of control jumps to the next statement just after the 'for'
>   loop.
>
> After the body of the 'for' loop executes, the flow of control jumps
>   back up to the increment statement. This statement allows you to
>   update any loop control variables.

Considering your first program statement:

```
 for(foo(); (int i = 5)==5 ; ++i)std::cout << i;
```

The above statement will give you following error (compiled using GCC):

```
    error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
        for(foo(); (int i = 5) == 5; ++i)std::cout << i; 

    error: expected ‘)’ before ‘int’
```

Primary Expression in `C` can be any of quite a number of things:

```
a name (of a variable or a function)
a typename
an operator
a keyword like if or while
the list goes on and on ...
```

This error is due to the fact that statement `(int i = 5) == 5` is not a valid expression and compiler is trying to interpret in some other way. However, the second program works as `int i = 5` declaration can be used as a valid condition for `condition` checking in for loop as the such declaration evaluates to value of `initializer` which is `5` in your second program. However, the second program will be an infinite loop and will keep printing `5` to the terminal.However, if the value of initializer was `0`, then the condition evalautes to false at it's first check and `for` loop body will not be executed even once.

Comment: The quote you gave says nothing about declaring variables in the "condition" part, it only mentions declarations in the "init" part (which would hint that declarations are not allowed in the other parts). Also, there may be differences between C and C++.

Comment: I mentioned it below " However, the second program works as int i = 5 declaration can be used as a valid condition for condition checking in for loop as the such declaration evaluates to value of initializer which is 5 in your second program. "